# I want to Strip all HTML tags, except allowed, if not allowed then show it as code

Tags: php

I want to Strip all HTML tags, except allowed. If the Strip not allowed then show it as code.

Example, I set the `<img>` not allowed.
then it should be show the code `<img src='test.png'/>`

Here is the code

```
$contant = "<img src='https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/12509125_1030730173658169_7327004625857771641_n.jpg?oh=15a789ac1e0433b400855006cb997626&oe=5748CF8C&__gda__=1464273191_9f0e8771a1d3cbef3940082e5677cc52'/>";
echo strip_tags($contant,'<b><p>');
```

On above code, it should be show the code `<img src='https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/12509125_1030730173658169_7327004625857771641_n.jpg?oh=15a789ac1e0433b400855006cb997626&oe=5748CF8C&__gda__=1464273191_9f0e8771a1d3cbef3940082e5677cc52'/>`

I tried on above code, the code is not display.
My question, how can I show the code?

Comment: The correct spelling is `content` =)

Comment: So what should happen to `<b>` and `<p>` tags?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking to strip everything but the <img> tag?

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags means remove the tags that not allowed in the list you give,then keep the contents which exculde the given tags.

So,what you need is simply

```
$contant = "<img src='https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/12509125_1030730173658169_7327004625857771641_n.jpg?oh=15a789ac1e0433b400855006cb997626&oe=5748CF8C&__gda__=1464273191_9f0e8771a1d3cbef3940082e5677cc52'/>";
echo strip_tags($contant,'<img>');
```